# QueryString values removed from the IPN endpoint by PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We've had a simple payment integration with PayPal for 5 years that has run without issue until today. In the IPN URL (`notify_url`) we pass 3 values in the querystring e.g.

```
https://www.example.com/callback/ipn?pspId=A&secCode=MnBP%2fxOwbQhXLd%2arD5xd6g%3d%3d&isPur=false
```

From today PayPal strip the last 2 values and call with just the first querystring value, e.g.

```
https://www.example.com/callback/ipn?pspId=A
```

We use the `secCode` value as a signature that we verify on the callback to prevent any modification of the form. Why would PayPal suddenly start stripping out values from the querystring? I suspect they should be in the POST but I'm just not sure why the sudden change?

Comment: We have noticed exactly the same problem with the `custom` value.  `custom` is a pass-through value that we set when creating the payment, and read in the callback.  We have it formatted as a query string - so key-value pairs separated by ampersands.  As of late March 7, we noticed that only the first value was coming back.

Comment: If it's any help, within 2 hours of posting this PayPal started to call our full notify URL again (querystring values preserved). Just waiting to see if this will hold.

Comment: OK we've now seen cases again where they remove all querystring values after the 1st. I believe they have differing logic depending on the server that picks up the payment request. We're moving these values to the POST now just to be safe.

Comment: The results were random for us too - I assumed that PayPal hard partially rolled out a breaking change.  At a rough guess, about 75% of our callbacks contained a truncated `custom` value.  We've now replaced the `&` separator with `|`, and that has resolved our issue.  That works for us, because `custom` is not a URL.

Comment: We can confirm as well. Only about 1 in 10 callbacks worked today. The ones that did not work only had the first parameter with the rest dropped. Also, some of the "http response code" were blank on the IPN history page.

Comment: @srbrussell we've also seen blank HTTP response codes in the past and that was because we were sending the `notify_url` with a leading white space. Oddly it worked for years like this, but PayPal have made some changes to the their IPN flow lately and they've tightened up on these things. @Mike, this is exactly what we are seeing, termination at the first ampersand, if we URL encode the full `notify_url` value then I think this mitigates the problem, although still testing.

Comment: So what's the question? Are you asking for a documentation of this change? Are you asking how to overcome this? "Why would PP do this?" is not really an on-topic question.

Comment: Does every comment need to be a question? Or could it just be an observation?

Answer (score 3):

OK we have now realised that *some* of PayPal's servers are terminating at the first ampersand. This explains why we get the first query string value but not others.

It seems this behaviour is not just limited to `notify_url` value but as is suggested by Mike in the comments, this is happening with the `CUSTOM` field too. If you're pushing through a series of name value pairs with an ampersand separator you need to either switch to some other separator or URL Encode the whole value.

We're just now testing to see if URL Encoding the whole callback URL will still result in an actual callback being made.

*EDIT:*

Yes URL encoding the whole `notify_url` value resolved the issue and preserved the query string.

*EDIT 2:*

It seems URL encoding the whole value no longer works, so I'm assuming PayPal have reverted back to the original behaviour before we encountered these problems. Hopefully this will be consistent across all their inbound servers and will remain fixed now.

Comment: But when I urlencode(cancel_return) then the &amp; stays in URL and clicking on it will result in error. I thought Paypal would urlencode the cancel_return?

Comment: I didn't test `cancel_return` however encoding the full `notify_url` did not cause any issues as PayPal are decoding the values before calling that endpoint.