# PayPal stripping variables on the return url query

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Yesterday I was notified that a site I administer wasn't sending e-mail notifications of successful orders to clients and to the assigned people in charge of processing the order for shipment.

I made a test transaction and noticed that the return url given on the generated html of the payment button which has 2 variables like this:

```
http://example.com/return?var1=something&var2=something2
```

Was stripped by paypal to:

```
http://example.com/return?var1=something
```

Also the ipn notification wasn't triggered correctly and also the ipn url makes use of more than 1 GET variables which it seems that paypal is also stripping.

I found this other report here on stackoverflow:

[QueryString values removed from the IPN endpoint by PayPal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669566/querystring-values-removed-from-the-ipn-endpoint-by-paypal)

It answers lots of questions, but the big question is:

¿Should I wait for paypal to finish whatever they are doing on their backend or should I make changes to my codebase that adapt to this undocumented changes?

Other references:

[PayPal IPN Unexpected Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726498/paypal-ipn-unexpected-changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a response from PayPal today (3/15) that they have fixed the issue.  (I submitted a report on ~3/10.)  Hopefully it is fully resolved and you won't have to make any modifications.

Comment: This is great news! I noticed orders where processing normally but wasn't sure, thanks for reporting!