# PayPal IPN works not as expected

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using an own written download software for paid downloads over paypal. This worked for the last years without any problems, but the last days there are some problems occurred with the IPN from PayPal.  Each download has a own form, the for looks like this

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" target="_top" method="post" target="_top" style="text-align: right">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller@example.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="SOME PRODUCT Single License">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="20001"> <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="69">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR"><input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.example.com/path1/path2/path3/?no_cache=1&tx_ppdownload_pi1%5Baction%5D=notify&tx_ppdownload_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=Transaction">
<input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="http://www.example.com/files/logo.png">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.example.com/path1/path2/path3/?no_cache=1&tx_ppdownload_pi1%5Baction%5D=return&tx_ppdownload_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=Transaction">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://www.example.com/path1/path2/path3/?no_cache=1&tx_ppdownload_pi1%5Baction%5D=cancel&tx_ppdownload_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=Transaction">
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" style="border-radius: 0;">Purchase now <br /><small>secure via PayPal</small></button>
```

There a multiple forms on the page with different products. Since a few days, I have this problems:

Sandbox and live: After purchase, there is a new layout and a new link to return to the shop. A few days ago, that link called my return url, with some get/post data. Included in that data was the txn_id. On the notify url sends PayPal always the transaction, and with the return url and the txnid I was able to check the transaction and show some information.

The cancel url is ignored too. I can click the button and then I came to paypal. A few days ago I was able to click there on cancel, and came back to the cancel_return to show some information. The cancel_return is in most cases now:

https://www.example.com/path1/path2/path3/?no_cache=1

without the other parameters. In 7 of 10 cases, the additional parameters are not in the cancel link at paypal page.

And in 7 of 10 cases, the notify_url gets never called, maybe there are the parameters missed too.

in 10 of 10 cases the return_url does not include the txn_id and in 7 out of 10 cases the return url has missed parameters from my forms.

the first bad payment (got the money, no correct return_url and no call on the notify_url was a few days ago). In last month I had around 60 transactions from different pages with different products, all without error.

I have no idea what's wrong now.

Comment: What is all of that after `no_cache=1`? It seems like the URL may not be what you want.

Comment: Hello aynber, thx for your comment. It is a MVC application. The other parameters are the controller/actions that the IPN have to call. This parameters are important to show the user the right content (return with completed/pending/failed) or the cancel_return. If the parameters are missed in the URLS, the users sees only the page with the products.

Comment: As i can now see, on the live system the missing parameter urls occours, if the buyer is logged in into PayPal. The notify_url, the return and the cancel_return are processed correctly, if there is no paypal login/session on the clients browser. How weird is this?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of March 8, 2017, a problem began to occur with PayPal's IPN handling.  When a transaction passes a url (return, cancel_return, and notify_url) that contains an '&' (such as when separating multiple values), PayPal is stripping the url of all content after the first '&'.

This post was one of the first to report the issue and recommends using urlencode: [QueryString values removed from the IPN endpoint by PayPal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669566/querystring-values-removed-from-the-ipn-endpoint-by-paypal)

I have made some modifications to my own PayPal form replacing just the '&' with `'&amp;'` (the encoded version) and that seems to work too.

This issue has been reported to PayPal (probably by many people by now); hopefully they will get it fixed.  Note also that the issue appears to be intermittent and as the above linked post mentions, it may be dependent on the PayPal server you connect to.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. It seems that the notify_url encoded now works every time. cancel_url and return_url not. I hope PayPal can fix this issue fast.

Comment: Do you have any information whether this is a bug on PayPal's side or whether they always required it and not just started to enforce it?

Comment: I've send a support request to paypal last week. ASAP i have a answer to this i publish it here.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: that is a good question.  I know they are rolling out a new 'checkout experience' but I wasn't able to find in the release notes for it any information affecting this issue.

Comment: I just checked their button generator and it does not escape anything. So this seems very much like a bug. Have you tried contacting PayPal about it?

Comment: I have today multiple transactions over my software done. It seems that the live system works now as expected. All return_url and notify_url works with parameters (escaped) without any problems so far. Hopefully PP solved this.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - agreed.  Yes, I did submit a report to them.  I have not heard a response.

Comment: I received a response today (3/15) from PayPal that, yes, it was a PayPal bug and it has now been fixed.  Hopefully that resolves the issue.