# Not getting pay pal ipn

Tags: paypal-ipn

I am not recieving the paypal IPN neither it is sending any error.I have check the connection with Tls check it responds with the message PayPal_Connection_OK. But still I am not getting the IPN. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php


class IpnListener {

    /**
     *  If true, the recommended cURL PHP library is used to send the post back 
     *  to PayPal. If flase then fsockopen() is used. Default true.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $use_curl = true;     

    /**
     *  If true, explicitly sets cURL to use SSL version 3. Use this if cURL
     *  is compiled with GnuTLS SSL.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $force_ssl_v3 = true;     

    /**
     *  If true, cURL will use the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to follow any 
     *  "Location: ..." headers in the response.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $follow_location = false;     

    /**
     *  If true, an SSL secure connection (port 443) is used for the post back 
     *  as recommended by PayPal. If false, a standard HTTP (port 80) connection
     *  is used. Default true.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $use_ssl = true;      

    /**
     *  If true, the paypal sandbox URI www.sandbox.paypal.com is used for the
     *  post back. If false, the live URI www.paypal.com is used. Default false.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $use_sandbox = false; 

    /**
     *  The amount of time, in seconds, to wait for the PayPal server to respond
     *  before timing out. Default 30 seconds.
     *
     *  @var int
     */
    public $timeout = 30;       

    private $post_data = array();
    private $post_uri = '';     
    private $response_status = '';
    private $response = '';

    const PAYPAL_HOST = 'ipnpb.paypal.com';
    const SANDBOX_HOST = 'ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com';

    /**
     *  Post Back Using cURL
     *
     *  Sends the post back to PayPal using the cURL library. Called by
     *  the processIpn() method if the use_curl property is true. Throws an
     *  exception if the post fails. Populates the response, response_status,
     *  and post_uri properties on success.
     *
     *  @param  string  The post data as a URL encoded string
     */
    protected function curlPost($encoded_data) {

        if ($this->use_ssl) {
            $uri = 'https://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
            $this->post_uri = $uri;
        } else {
            $uri = 'https://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
            $this->post_uri = $uri;
        }

        $ch = curl_init();

        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        // // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_data);
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $this->follow_location);
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

         $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_data);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 
                    dirname(__FILE__)."/cert/cacert.pem");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

        if ($this->force_ssl_v3) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
        } 
        else {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 (6));
        }

        $this->response = curl_exec($ch);
        $this->response_status = strval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));

        if ($this->response === false || $this->response_status == '0') {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Post Back Using fsockopen()
     *
     *  Sends the post back to PayPal using the fsockopen() function. Called by
     *  the processIpn() method if the use_curl property is false. Throws an
     *  exception if the post fails. Populates the response, response_status,
     *  and post_uri properties on success.
     *
     *  @param  string  The post data as a URL encoded string
     */
    protected function fsockPost($encoded_data) {

        if ($this->use_ssl) {
            $uri = 'tsl://'.$this->getPaypalHost();
            $port = '443';
            $this->post_uri = $uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        } else {
            $uri = $this->getPaypalHost(); // no "http://" in call to fsockopen()
            $port = '80';
            $this->post_uri = 'https://'.$uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        }

        $fp = fsockopen($uri, $port, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout);

        if (!$fp) { 
            // fsockopen error
            throw new Exception("fsockopen error: [$errno] $errstr");
        } 

        $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $header .= "Host: ipnb.sanbox.paypal.com\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($encoded_data)."\r\n";
        $header .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

        fputs($fp, $header.$encoded_data."\r\n\r\n");

        while(!feof($fp)) { 
            if (empty($this->response)) {
                // extract HTTP status from first line
                $this->response .= $status = fgets($fp, 1024); 
                $this->response_status = trim(substr($status, 9, 4));
            } else {
                $this->response .= fgets($fp, 1024); 
            }
        } 

        fclose($fp);
    }

    private function getPaypalHost() {
        if ($this->use_sandbox) return self::SANDBOX_HOST;
        else return self::PAYPAL_HOST;
    }

    /**
     *  Get POST URI
     *
     *  Returns the URI that was used to send the post back to PayPal. This can
     *  be useful for troubleshooting connection problems. The default URI
     *  would be "ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com:443/cgi-bin/webscr"
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getPostUri() {
        return $this->post_uri;
    }

    /**
     *  Get Response
     *
     *  Returns the entire response from PayPal as a string including all the
     *  HTTP headers.
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getResponse() {
        return $this->response;
    }

    /**
     *  Get Response Status
     *
     *  Returns the HTTP response status code from PayPal. This should be "200"
     *  if the post back was successful. 
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getResponseStatus() {
        return $this->response_status;
    }

    /**
     *  Get Text Report
     *
     *  Returns a report of the IPN transaction in plain text format. This is
     *  useful in emails to order processors and system administrators. Override
     *  this method in your own class to customize the report.
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getTextReport() {

        $r = '';

        // date and POST url
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n[".date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - '.$this->getPostUri();
        if ($this->use_curl) $r .= " (curl)\n";
        else $r .= " (fsockopen)\n";

        // HTTP Response
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n{$this->getResponse()}\n";

        // POST vars
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n";

        foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
            $r .= str_pad($key, 25)."$value\n";
        }
        $r .= "\n\n";

        return $r;
    }

    /**
     *  Process IPN
     *
     *  Handles the IPN post back to PayPal and parsing the response. Call this
     *  method from your IPN listener script. Returns true if the response came
     *  back as "VERIFIED", false if the response came back "INVALID", and 
     *  throws an exception if there is an error.
     *
     *  @param array
     *
     *  @return boolean
     */    
    public function processIpn($post_data=null) {

        $encoded_data = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        if ($post_data === null) { 
            // use raw POST data 
            if (!empty($_POST)) {
                $this->post_data = $_POST;
                $encoded_data .= '&'.file_get_contents('php://input');
            } else {
                throw new Exception("No POST data found.");
            }
        } else { 
            // use provided data array
            $this->post_data = $post_data;

            foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
                $encoded_data .= "&$key=".urlencode($value);
            }
        }

        if ($this->use_curl) $this->curlPost($encoded_data); 
        else $this->fsockPost($encoded_data);

        if (strpos($this->response_status, '200') === false) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid response status: ".$this->response_status);
        }

        if (strpos($this->response, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
            return true;
        } elseif (strpos($this->response, "INVALID") !== false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected response from PayPal.");
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Require Post Method
     *
     *  Throws an exception and sets a HTTP 405 response header if the request
     *  method was not POST. 
     */    
    public function requirePostMethod() {
        // require POST requests
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
            header('Allow: POST', true, 405);
            throw new Exception("Invalid HTTP request method.");
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to make sure PayPal is calling the correct IPN listener URL?  You can log into PayPal and check your 'IPN History' (https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history) to make sure.  You can also check all the other IPN data to see if it's correct.

I mention this specifically because, in the last few days, PayPal has been stripping the notify_url that I send to it.  I discovered the issue by checking the IPN history.  (You can see more about this issue here: [QueryString values removed from the IPN endpoint by PayPal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669566/querystring-values-removed-from-the-ipn-endpoint-by-paypal))